# Finding all sets of possibly overlapping fragments that makes up the whole?

Tags: algorithm, graph, combinations, combinatorics

Let us say the `space = [0, 100]` and there are a number of intervals given.

These intervals are fragments of the space, and possibly overlap.

```
[0, 30], [0, 20], [10, 40], [30, 50], [50, 90], [70, 100]
```

is a set of intervals.

An example of a set of intervals that span the entire space chosen from the above set is:

```
[0, 30], [10, 40], [30, 50], [50, 90], [70, 100]
```

Another example is

```
[0, 30], [30, 50], [50, 90], [70, 100]
```

which is the set in the previous example without `[10, 40]`.

I want to find all combinations of such sets of intervals to calculate cost for each interval and find the one with the lowest cost.

```py
from operator import itemgetter
import collections

tmp = [(0, 30), (0, 20), (10, 40), (30, 50), (50, 90), (70, 100), ]
aa = sorted(tmp, key=itemgetter(1)) # sort with respect to 1st elem
a = set(aa)
space = 100
d_conn = 15
RTT = d_conn*2
bandwidth = 10

def get_marginal_cost(fragment):
    return RTT + (fragment[1] - fragment[0])/bandwidth

def dfs(a, start, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = [start, ]
    if start[1] == space:
        yield path
    for frgmt in a - set(path):
        l = frgmt[0]
        r = frgmt[1]
        if start[0] < l <= start[1] <= r:
#        if l <= start[1] <= r:
            yield dfs(a, frgmt, path + [frgmt, ])

for z in a:
    if z[0] == 0:
        for output in list(dfs(a, z)):
            for outpu in list(output):
                for outp in list(outpu):
                    for out in list(outp):
                        for ou in list(out):
                            print list(ou)
```

This is my attempt so far, but I could not finish.

Particularly, I am looking to finish this without use of `yield` functionality in Python, because I am not familiar with it and I probably want to implement this in C++.

Can anyone help me write a working program that solves this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: it seems like you might be unclear on what problem exactly you are trying to solve. please clarify.

Comment: The problem is simple and I believe I clearly specified the problem at the beginning.

Comment: `find all combinations of such sets of intervals to calculate cost for each interval` seems to suggest the contribution of each interval depends on the combination. (wait - that might contradict the added qualification `simple`)

Comment: @user2418202 The answer depends on what your cost function is.  If it is an **arbitrary** function of the number and lengths of the intervals, then brute force is the only answer.  If it takes a more specific form, then there might be a good solution.  What is your cost function?

Comment: You can find my cost function in ideone.com/oN4jWa which also contains my attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to explicitly build the tree - you could use a recursive depth first search to achieve the same effect.

At each point in the recursive depth first search you will have built a set of intervals covering [0,x] and you will want to extend this. To do this you need to find all of the intervals which intersect with x and end after x. As you recurse down the tree you will want to do the same search for y > x and so on.

One way to speed this up would be to put the start and end points of the intervals into an array and sort them. You keep a pointer into the array which marks the position x and a set of intervals that cover x, perhaps stored as a hash set. When you advance the position x you move the pointer along the list, deleting intervals from the set when you see their right hand points, and adding intervals to the set when you see their left hand points. You can back up in a very similar way.

This should allow you to keep track of what intervals you can use to extend the covering [0,x] at each point without searching through every possible interval.

This should allow you to enumerate the list of all possible coverings reasonably efficiently. To find the cheapest covering without enumerating all possible coverings we would need to know more about the cost function than you have put in the question.

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying to find the solution using the DFS path finding, but had little luck. The closest I got (borrowed algorithm from http://eddmann.com/posts/depth-first-search-and-breadth-first-search-in-python/ ) was http://ideone.com/yrmXEH but I was not familiar with `yield` keyword and `generator` objects were hard to deal with. This is not even finding the minimum cost, but just printing the path. Also, it didn't seem like there's `recursive DFS path searching algorithm` without a use of `yield` functionality in Python. Can you take a look and see what I could do, or

Comment: could you give me some sample code in either python or c++? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it really necessary to build a tree just to find the minimum cost?

Probably not (assuming that your currently unspecified cost function displays optimal substructure).

For a linear cost function, the following classic algorithm runs in time O(n log n), where n is the number of intervals. Initialize a sorted map from mid to the cost of covering [0, mid]. Initially, this map has one entry, 0 -> 0. Sort the intervals by right endpoint and process them in order as follows. To process [a, b], find the map entry mid -> cost such that mid >= a is as small as possible. (If no such entry exists, then just continue.) Let cost' = cost + Cost([a, b]), where Cost([a, b]) is unspecified but always positive. While the last entry in the map has cost greater than or equal to cost', delete it. Insert b -> cost'. To finish, look up the successor of end, where [0, end] is the space to be covered.

Even if your cost function is not linear, since it's a (presumably monotone) function of the total interval length and the number of intervals, we can get an O(n^2)-time algorithm that, instead of remembering just one cost for each midpoint, remembers for each integer between 0 and n the cost for a solution that uses the specified number of intervals.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure this can be optimised, but below is a working version. Will try to optimize it and update again:

```
from operator import itemgetter
import collections
import random

def generate_sample_input(space):
    # This method generates a set of tuples, each tuple consisting of 2 nos
    low, high = space
    init = (low, random.randint(low + 1, (low + high)/2))
    last = (random.randint((low + high)/2 + 1, high), high)
    mid = random.randint(init[1] + 1, last[0] - 1)
    ranges = [init, (init[1] - 1, mid + 1), (mid - 1, last[0] + 1), last]
    nums = {i for tup in ranges for i in tup}
    for _ in range(random.randint(0, 20)):
        low = random.randint(space[0], space[1] - 1)
        high = random.randint(low, space[1])
        if all(i not in nums for i in (low, high)):
            nums |= {low, high}
            ranges.append((low, high))
    return sorted(set(ranges), key = lambda x: x[0])

class Node(object):

    def __init__(self, tup):
        assert len(tup) == 2 and all(type(x) == int for x in tup)
        self.low, self.high = tup
        self.visitable_nodes = []
        self.piggybacker_nodes = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return "(%s, %s)" % (self.low, self.high)

    def set_visitable(self, node):
        assert type(node) == Node
        if self.low < node.low and node.high < self.high:
            self.piggybacker_nodes.append(node)
        elif self.low < node.low < self.high:
            self.visitable_nodes.append(node)

class Graph(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.sources, self.sinks, self.nodes = [], [], []

    def add(self, node, is_sink=False, is_source=False):
        assert type(node) == Node and not (is_sink and is_source)
        for old_node in self.nodes:
            old_node.set_visitable(node)
            node.set_visitable(old_node)
        self.nodes.append(node)
        if is_sink:
            self.sinks.append(node)
        elif is_source:
            self.sources.append(node)

    def create_graph(self, ranges=[], space=[]):
        for tup in ranges:
            self.add(Node(tup), is_source=tup[0]==space[0], 
                     is_sink=tup[1]==space[1])

def dfs(stack=[], nodes=[], sinks=[], level=0):
    for node in nodes:
        if node in sinks:
            print stack + [node]
        dfs(stack + [node], node.visitable_nodes, sinks, level + 1)

def main():
    space = (0, 100)
    ranges = generate_sample_input(space)
    graph = Graph()
    graph.create_graph(space=space, ranges=ranges)
    print ranges
    dfs([], nodes=graph.sources, sinks=graph.sinks)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```